# WebAPI Controller redirects to raw JSON view when called via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I am trying to call a WebAPI controller. The controller works fine when I call it via $.get in jQuery. After finishing the callback function everything should stop and I should be able to see my web page. However after finishing the callback function the browser is taking me to the raw JSON view page in chrome. In IE it asks me if I want to download returned .json file. Why is this happening. Here is my code:

```
function onNLookupSearch() {
    var uri = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    var searchTerm = $("#nlookupsearch").val();
    var resultUrl = window.location.href = uri + "/api/v1/GetNetworkName?networkName=" + searchTerm;
    $.get(resultUrl, function (data1) {
        localData1 = data1;

        $("#sdnetworkselect").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: localData1,
            dataTextField: "NETWORK_NAME",
            dataValueField: "NETWORK_ID"
        });
        $("#hdnetworkselect").kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: localData1,
            dataTextField: "NETWORK_NAME",
            dataValueField: "NETWORK_ID"
        });
      });
    }
```

Here is my WebAPI controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using CPT2.Data;

namespace CPT2.Controllers
{
    public class GetNetworkNameController : ApiController
    {
        private CMDBdbContext _ctx;

        public GetNetworkNameController(CPT2.Data.CMDBdbContext ctx)
        {
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        public IQueryable<CPT2.Data.network_sourceid_map> Get([FromUri] string networkName)
        {
            var result =
                _ctx.network_sourceid_map.Where(
                    nw => nw.NETWORK_NAME.Contains(networkName) || nw.SOURCE_NAME.Contains(networkName));
            var myList = result.Select(item => item.NETWORK_NAME + " - " + item.SOURCE_NAME + " [" + item.SOURCE_ID + "]").ToList();
            //return myList;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Lets assume I search for "ESPN". That's the search term in the code above.

After this function is done I should stay on page however I am redirected to a raw view of the returned data by Chrome and IE asks me to save a JSON file.

Comment: Please clarify.  You say "The controller works fine when I call it via $.get in jQuery. ".  When does it not work correctly?  are you using a different jquery ajax method?

Comment: Well when I call the controller via get I do get JSON back and I can work on the returned data in the callback. But immediately after I am redirected to this page with raw JSON. Why am I being redirected on a $.get. That's not normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is this line:

```
var resultUrl = window.location.href = uri + "/api/v1/GetNetworkName?networkName=" + searchTerm;
```

You are setting the window.location.href which is redirecting the entire page to the API "page", which is why you're getting a .json file.

Comment: Wow. I think I was tired that day. Sorry. Great pick Josh. Thanks. Happens to the best of us. :). Long Live Stack Overflow.